# How do I model the optimization of haircuts (price vs. frequency vs. satisfaction)?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

My goal is to use a simple, real world situation to apply optimization algorithms to and find optimal choices based on computation. What information do I need to gather and what questions do I need to ask? In the end, I want to be able to say that yearly pattern $x$ of haircuts is the most optimal based on price, frequency, and satisfaction. How do I begin to define the variables of this problem? How would I even model satisfaction level??

**Example inputs:**

hair growth rate = 1 inch/month

satisfaction =

a. 3 inches = 10/10 (perfect satisfaction)

b. 3.5 inches = 9/10

c. 4 inches = 8/10

d. 5 inches = 5.5/10 (sharp decline)

e. 6 inches = 4.5/10

price of haircut = $20 (ludicrous, I know)

Comment: You have to define the satisfaction levels. They must be depend on the length of the hairs.

Comment: satisfaction levels seems subjective in this case different people care differently about there hair. that being said you can look up the growth rate of hair, the average price, average income, and average desired hair length and probability of a good hair cut,this will give you an aproximation of the best average frequency. I suggest splitting girls and boys due to radical difference in figures.

Comment: Editing the question based on both of your comments.